# CCAnimation, how to set frame rate for individual frames

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Let's say I have an animation consisting of five frames.
How would I set frames 1-4 to play for 0.5 seconds each, then the 5th frame for 0.1 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this yet, (new in cocos 2.x), but :

```
CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animation];
NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray array];
CCSpriteFrame *sfr1 = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"name1"];
CCAnimationFrame *af1 = [[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:sfr1 delayUnits:5 userInfo:nil] autorelease];
[frames addObject:af1];

// tru sfr4 and finally

CCSpriteFrame *sfr5 = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"name5"];
CCAnimationFrame *af5 = [[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:sfr5 delayUnits:1 userInfo:nil] autorelease];
[frames addObject:af5];

anim = [CCAnimation animationWithAnimationFrames:frames delayPerUnit:.1 loops:1];
```

This should give you the effect you are looking for.

ps : userInfo is an NSDictionary. When the animation is played you can register for a notification named CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification, and receive the userInfo, frame by frame.

// not tested , yet //

Comment: oh, so *that* is how it's supposed to work? Hmmm now I remember there was some talk about an animation system/file format with individual frame delays.

Comment: yes, and the long awaited callback per frame, using the notification center. No real use in my current app, but cant wait to shake the tires on this one.

Comment: Finally tried this. It seems to work. I ended up using it for another animation consisting only of 3 frames. The first two have a 0.1 frame ratio and the last one 0, because I wanted something to react as soon as the last frame was being displayed. I'll definitely be using this more later.

Answer (score 1):

By playing the animation manually. Schedule a selector, use its delta time to see if you need to switch to the next frame. Use setDisplayFrame: to change the sprite's frame.

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate animation, one with 0.5 second and one with 0.2second.